# Is there a libraray/method for 80 column formatted text output?

Tags: c++, text, word-wrap, reflow

Here is what I'm looking for.

I'd like to find a library or method that formats output text, such that it word wraps at
80 columns (or user configurable), and allows user defined indentation.

I know that I could create one, but I suspect that there is already a library available
that does this. I've googled around and I've found pages for iomanip -- which gave me
ideas for creating my own.

I've done a cursory search through the boost libraries, but I didn't really find anything that quite matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is, search harder next time ;)

2.2.4. Line-Wrapping Filters

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/line_wrapping_filters.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a POSIX platform, you could look at ncurses or termcap and see if they will accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/catchorg/textflowcpp is probably the best way to do this nowadays.